# Embed video iframe in facebook wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am attempting to embed an HTML5 video player on the Facebook wall in an iframe similar to Youtube or Flash videos. I cannot use Flash for political reasons. The player must have the company branding.

Youtube is using something as follows to signal opengraph:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="video">
<meta property="og:video:url" content="https://www.youtube.com/embed/[id]">
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://www.youtube.com/embed/[id]">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="text/html">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="1280">
<meta property="og:video:height" content="720">
<meta property="og:video:url" content="http://www.youtube.com/v/[id]?autohide=1&amp;version=3">
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://www.youtube.com/v/[id]?autohide=1&amp;version=3">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="1280">
<meta property="og:video:height" content="720">
```

The embed-URI itself returns a page with a full window video player.

I have set up a full width video player page myself and directed to it using similar opengraph tags (and removing the Flash-ones). This however does not work.

Does anyone know the secret sauce?

[edit]

As there was a question which tags I was using, I copied the HTML5 part from the YouTube video. Apparently this doesn't work because you have to be whitelisted by Facebook...

```
<meta property="og:type" content="video">
<meta property="og:video:url" content="https://myembedurl.com/video.html">
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://myembedurl.com/video.html">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="text/html">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="1280">
<meta property="og:video:height" content="720">
```

Comment: You should provide a link to your video so people can check your tags. Anyway, I'd recommend go to the docs and find the appropriate tags for the type of video you want to embed (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph) there are different types of videos but normally you should use video.other

Comment: @JavierdelaCueva The tags are the same as the YouTube ones. Apparently it doesn't work because you have to be whitelisted in order for this to work.

Comment: Hi MrP, I guess I'd need to know first what do you mean with "does not work", what's exactly the problem? is that the video does not reproduce? or it is shown but not in full mode? Would you mind please clarify it? Also, I'm pretty sure you do not have to be whitelisted for anything related to videos.

Comment: @JavierdelaCueva With "it does not work" I mean that the video is not embedded. The video url specified in url is inserted into a <video>-element. As it is an HTML page, the content cannot be played like this, but should be embedded as an iframe.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to your video so I can test it? Thanks!

Comment: Have you found a way to share in Facebook an iframe instead of the video element? I'm using the og:video:type as "text/html" and the og:type with "my_namespace:object_type" with an object I created in the app's open graph settings but no luck. My post content is being added as a video element instead of an iframe. Do I need to submit my app for review or whitelisting?